# How Can I Compare two DateTime whether in a same season in EntityFramwork

Tags: c#, entity-framework

What I want is to check if there are dates in the database that are in the same season as the current date, but I can not use this Entity Framework function:

```
 Db.Article.Any(item=>EntityFunctions.DiffMonths(DateTime.Now,item.ForDate)<=3)
```

Does Entity Framework provide a function for this? If not, how do I do it?

Comment: Two dates in different seasons are not necessarily three months apart. They could be 1 day apart.

Comment: You said exactly what I confused!!@dcastro

Answer (score 1):

Differences between dates is a `TimeSpan` in .NET, and it's simple to calculate. Edit your code to something like this :

```
Db.Article.Any(item => (DateTime.Now - item.ForDate).Days <=3 );
```

and you'r good to go!

Comment: but how can i use TimeSpan to solve my season question. the example code i writed just use to explain my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no native SQL function that can do what you want, I see two options.  Number 1, if you can pull back the whole table (which you may not be able to, if the table is large) then you can write an extension method to convert a date into a season.  For instance:

```
public enum Seasons
{
    Spring,
    Summer,
    Autumn,
    Winter
}  

public class SeasonDates
{
    public static DateTime SpringStart(int year)
    {
        return new DateTime(year, 3, 20);
    }

    public static DateTime SummerStart(int year)
    {
        return new DateTime(year, 6, 21);
    }

    public static DateTime AutumnStart(int year)
    {
        return new DateTime(year, 9, 23);
    }

    public static DateTime WinterStart(int year)
    {
        return new DateTime(year, 12, 22);
    }
}

public static class MyExtensions
{   
    public static Seasons GetSeason(this DateTime date)
    {
        var result = Seasons.Winter;

        if (date >= SeasonDates.SpringStart(date.Year) && date < SeasonDates.WinterStart(date.Year))
            result = Seasons.Autumn;
        else if (date >= SeasonDates.SummerStart(date.Year))
            result = Seasons.Summer;
        else if (date >= SeasonDates.SpringStart(date.Year))
            result = Seasons.Spring;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Then, you can call it like:

```
Db.Article.Select(a => a.ForDate).ToList().Any(d => d.GetSeason() == DateTime.Now.GetSeason());
```

*Note, this implementation will not be 100% accurate since the first day of the seasons can vary from year to year.

The other option would be to write a stored procedure in SQL to retrieve the data for you.

Comment: thanks for your patience answer! but i don't think option1 is the good way to solve problem as you said, ! But still I have to thank you!